# Parsing JSON POST request C#

Tags: c#, json

Some serwer sends POST requests with the following information:

```
{
    payload: {
    uid: "900af657a65e",
    amount: 50,
    adjusted_amount: 25
},
 signature: "4dd0f5da77ecaf88628967bbd91d9506"
}
```

How shoud I successfully process that in my ASHX handler?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Comment: So what is it? In the 'documentation' example in Ruby I see that they use the JSON library to parse this

Comment: The keys need to be quoted.

Comment: OK. Lets assume that this is JSON and I know how to parse JSON string. How do I get this string from the POST request? I don't have any POST parameter specified which holds it(context.Request["????"])

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ will tell you what's wrong with it -- as Mike noted, the keys need to be quoted strings, not bare identifiers.

Comment: @user2441297 I edited my answer with some code to read the request body using context.Request.InputStream.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As SLaks noted, that's not valid JSON. But in general, a good solution for serializing/deserializing JSON in .NET is the JSON.NET library: http://json.codeplex.com/. There is plenty of documentation there that should get you started.

Edit: to read the request body, try something like

```
 string postData = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```