# How to read value when using model.save() or fetch()?

Tags: asp.net, json, backbone.js

```js
Man = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'/test.aspx',
        initialize: function(){
        },
        defaults: {
            name:'Jim',
            age: '38'
        },
        validate:function(attributes){
            if(attributes.name == '') {
                return "name can't be null";
            }
        }
    });
    var man = new Man;
    man.set({name:'the5fire'});
    man.save();  //the format is json{"name":"the5fire","age":38}
```

In `test.aspx.cs`, how can I read this value `{"name":"the5fire","age":38}` ?

I have tried `Request.Form.ToString()` but found no data there.

Chrome developer tools shows this json-format data in the "request payload" block.

---

update:

If I use `man.fetch({ data: { Pagesize: '1', PageIndex: '111' } )`, then on the server side, I can use `Request.Params["PageIndex"]`. But how can I get the name? the age?

Comment: the data will be serialized as JSON when sending the request from backbone

Comment: Yes, I juest don't konw how to get this JSON. I've only used Request.querystirng or Request.Form before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the raw body of the request via [`HttpRequest.InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and  [convert it to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221533/parsing-json-post-request-c-sharp) :

```cs
string jsonstring = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

You would then [deserialize this string to get an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object), for example:

```cs
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var d = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonstring);
string name = (string)d["name"];
```